# WIN2K8 R2 Public Message Queues

Tags: .net, msmq, public

I have a small domain (6 servers) and I need to use MSMQ.  The codebase for this project is from a 5 year old project at a company that used WIN2K3 servers, and all features worked properly.

I have enabled MSMQ features on all servers (including AD integration).

I have created PUBLIC queues on all servers.

When the code attempts to list all the public queues on a remote server, the code indicates there are 0 public queues.

```
MessageQueue[] MqList = MessageQueue.GetPublicQueuesByMachine(HostName);
```

It does not throw an exception, it simply cannot see the queues.

Also, when I connect to a remote machine with the Computer Management snap-in, I am not able to see the Message Queueing node.  I was able to see remote message queue nodes in WIN2K3. (See Image)[image]

I think it is a permission issue, but I have tried to open permissions as wide as possible and I am still getting no love.

Comment: I notice you are remotely connecting to the w2k8 server. Does it look the same if you go onto the server itself?

Answer (score 0):

The method `GetPublicQueuesByMachine()` is indeed **not** available over remote access.

You can see this in a feature matrix in the MSDN documentation: [MessageQueue.GetPublicQueuesByMachine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getpublicqueuesbymachine.aspx):

> The following table shows whether this method is available in various Workgroup modes.
>
> ```
>  Workgroup mode                         Available
>  --------------                         ---------
>  Local computer                         No
>  Local computer and direct format name  No
>  Remote computer                        No
>  Remote computer and direct format name No
> ```

I just recently found that most methods of the Queue class have a feature matrix like this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also found that the GetPublicQueuesByMachine method did not work on a Win2K8 server.

I found that GetPublicQueues DID work.  So I used it and pulled the queues I needed that way.